# Can I cancel my UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk

Recently, I made a mistake on my UK student visa application regarding my course fees. I entered £10050.00 instead of £10500.00 which was written in my CAS. I have already received my IHS Number, but I haven't paid for the visa application yet.

Can I cancel the application? Or should I just leave it as it is and create a new application? I received my IHS for free since I am using a student visa. Or should I just leave it since it is not a major error?

Comment: Are you sure you can’t just amend the figure? It is usually the case that a visa application isn’t finalised / classed as submitted until the fee has been paid